# Android bundle build error with Dynamic Features: All modules with native libraries must support the same set of ABI

Tags: android, android-studio, build, bundle

I'm adding dynamic feature to my application.

When I try to build my bundle, I'm getting error:

> All modules with native libraries must support the same set of ABIs,
> but module 'base' supports '[ARM64_V8A, ARMEABI_V7A, ARMEABI, MIPS,
> MIPS64, X86, X86_64]' and module 'Affiliate' supports '[ARM64_V8A,
> ARMEABI_V7A, X86, X86_64]'.

I did try to add the code to **build.gradle** in Dynamic Feature Module to resolve this issue:

```
defaultConfig{
        ndk {
            abiFilters.addAll(mutableSetOf("ARM64_V8A", "X86_64", "ARMEABI", "X86", "ARMEABI_V7A", "MIPS64", "MIPS"))
        }
    }
```

But not have effect, still getting error

Help!!!! how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `abiFilters` in base module too, not only in dynamic feature's gradle.
And also use lowercased filters too.

```
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        abiFilters "ARM64_V8A", "ARMEABI_V7A", "ARMEABI", "MIPS", "X86", "X86_64"
        abiFilters "arm64_v8a", "armeabi_v7a", "armeabi", "mips", "x86", "x86_64"
    }
}
```

Comment: But it will increase the app size. Can anyone suggest any solution to reduce it?

Comment: @abhishek-sharma You can build as Bundle. Yes, single apk and bundle files weight so heavy but it's size will be minimized while downloading

Comment: Yes I have used "arm64_v8a" & "armeabi_v7a" both for prod variants which reduces the size of the apk alot as these 2 architectures are the mostly used in android phones. Bundle will also reduce the size as you said !!